# How undecidable is it whether a given Turing machine runs in polynomial time?

Tags: computability, undecidability, polynomial-time

The proof of Theorem 1 that PTime is not semi-decidable [in this recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.04026v1.pdf) effectively shows that it is $\mathsf{R}\cup\mathsf{coR}$-hard. The proof itself is similar to undecidability proofs at  [cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14215/machines-in-p-undecidable) and [cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no). However, what is different is a footnote, which highlights that proving both $\mathsf{R}$-hardness and $\mathsf{coR}$-hardness seems to be new:

> <sup>1</sup>The undecidability of PTime seems to be folklore, but non-semi-decidability seems to be new, even though semi-decidability is a natural property here.

But I want to ignore the question whether this observation is new. What interests me is what is known about the degree of undecidability of PTime. For example, is [computation in the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit) powerful enough to decide PTime? Are there better lower bounds than $\mathsf{R}\cup\mathsf{coR}$ for the difficulty of PTime?

**Note**: I denote the problem to decide "whether a given Turing machine runs in polynomial time" as PTime here. I know that this is incorrect, because PTime is a class of languages and not a class of Turing machines. However, I found this misuse of terminology convenient for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\bf 0''$ (and so in particular computation in the limit - which corresponds to $\le_T\bf 0'$ - is not enough). And this stronger result is also folklore (I was assigned it as an exercise way back when).

As an upper bound we just check quantifier complexity: $\Phi_e$ runs in polynomial time iff *there exists* some polynomial $p$ such that *for every* input $n$ we have $\Phi_e(n)[p(\vert n\vert)]\downarrow$ (that final clause only uses bounded quantifiers). So running in polynomial time is a $\Sigma^0_2$ property.

Now we just need to show optimality. We'll actually show a bit more: not just that the Turing degree is $\bf 0''$, but that the set is $\Sigma^0_2$-complete. Supposing $$A=\{x:\exists y\forall z\theta(x,y,z)\}$$ (with $\theta\in\Delta^0_0$) is any other $\Sigma^0_2$ set, we want to reduce $A$ to the set of programs running in polynomial time.

So fix an instance $i$. We'll say *$m$ is $s$-bad for $i$* if $m<s$ and there is some $n<s$ such that $\neg\theta(i,m,n)$. Let $t_i(s)$ be the least $m$ which is not $s$-bad for $i$. Now we'll whip up a stupid program $\Phi_{e_i}$ as follows: on input $s$, $\Phi_{e_i}(s)$ runs for ${\vert s\vert}^{t_i(s)}$-many steps and then halts and outputs $0$. The point is that if $i\in A$ then $t_i(s)$ stabilizes and so $\Phi_{e_i}$ runs in polynomial time, and otherwise $\Phi_{e_i}$ does not run in polynomial time.

Now the map $\mu: i\mapsto e_i$ is computable, so we get a many-one reduction of $A$ to our set.

---

As a quick comment, note that we only used one property of polynomial time above: that there is no biggest polynomial time bound. This let us keep pushing up the runtime bit by bit (each time $t_i(s)$ goes up) while preserving the possibility of still running in polynomial time. By contrast, "halts within seven steps on all inputs" (say) is merely $\Pi^0_1$-complete. Basically, whenever we have a concrete resource-bounded complexity class with no "maximal bound," being in that class will be $\Sigma^0_2$-complete. In particular, this applies to NP, EXPTIME, PSPACE, ...

Comment: Doesn't the time required to compute $t_i(s)$ depend on $\theta$, and might eventually be superpolynomial in $s$? What am I missing

Comment: @Ariel We can always massage it so it doesn't. Basically, have $\hat{\theta}(x,y,z)$ iff a given "polytime-approximation" to $\theta$, with bound coming from $z$, holds on all $(x,y,z')$ for $z'<z$. The details are a bit messy to write down, and I'll put them in when I get the chance, but (i) your concern is very reasonable and (ii) it can be addressed through a generally automatic process.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like something along the lines of "for every monotone $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial time computable unbounded function $g(n)\le\log(n)$, such that $f(g)$ is polynomially bounded will do".