# Showing that a property is semantic - Rice's theorem

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, rice-theorem

I want to show that the language
$$L= \left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle \mid\substack{\text{M is a TM and there exists a poly TM $M'$ such that}\\
\text{if M halts on input $w$, $M'$ halts on $w$ and answers the same}
}
\right\}  $$
is not decideable, using Rice's theorem.

I have a hard time understanding why this property is semantic. I obviously can't assume that $M \in R$ , so it might be that we have TMs $M_{1},M_{2}$ such that $L(M_{1})=L(M_{2})$, but $M_{1}$ gets stuck on some input $z$, while $M_{2}$ rejects it. Then, the property above (having a poly TM which identifies with $M$ on inputs which it halts on) might possibly apply for $M_{1}$ but not for $M_{2}$ (as $M_{1}^{\prime}$ doesn't have to satisfy anything about $z$, while $M_{2}^{\prime}$ must reject it). But according to the exercise I have to use Rice's theorem, so I am probably missing something and this property is semantic after all.

I saw [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14215/machines-in-p-undecidable) related question but it didn't really help.

Comment: The condition only depends on $L(M)$, that is, it is semantic.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But the condition depends on $M$'s termination on inputs, that is, it is not (directly) semantic, as I mentioned in my question, what am I missing?

Comment: If you think of $L(M)$ as a partial function from $\Sigma^*$ to $\Sigma^*$, then the problem disappears.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for example, $M_1=\text{HALT}$ is in the said language, with $M_1^{\prime}=M_{\Sigma^{*}}$ (assuming correct encodings), but if I take $M_2=\text{HALT}^{\prime}$ which first checks if the encoding is of a *specific* infinite loop TM $N$, and rejects if it is equal to it, and else runs $M_1$ and answers the same, we have $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$ but the previous $M_1^{\prime}$ doesn't work anymore (as it should reject the specific TM $N$ mentioned above).

Comment: You have to define $L(M)$ accordingly. The upshot is that whether $\langle M \rangle$ is in the language or not depends only on what $M$ *computes*, not on *how* it computes it. We only care, for each input $x$, whether $M$ halts on $x$, and if so, what does it output. We don't care about anything beyond that.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus See my previous example, it might (theoretically) be that: there exists a poly TM $M^{\prime}$ that identifies with $M$ on inputs it halts on, but there isn't a poly TM $M^{\prime \prime}$ such that $L(M)=L(M^{\prime \prime})$ (which is a stronger condition, as we also reject inputs which M gets stuck on). What am I missing?

Comment: You don't actually have $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$, due to the difference on $N$.

Comment: Repeating, you have to define $L(M)$ as specifying, for each $x$, whether $M$ halts on $x$, and if so, the output. This is the semantic description of the partial function computed by $M$, and it suffices in order to decide membership in your language.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $M_1$ gets stuck on $N$, and $M_2$ rejects $N$, so $N \notin L(M_{i})$, and on other inputs they act the same, so $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$. (I should've noted that in the previous example $\text{HALT}$ operates as follows: given an input $M$ it simply emulates $M$ on an empty tape and accepts when $M$ halts - so it gets stuck if $M$ doesn't terminate).

Comment: If they don't act the same on some input, then the languages are not identical.

Comment: You can't use your definition here, because it doesn't capture all semantic properties of Turing machines.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In my definition $L\left(M\right)=\left\{ w\in\Sigma^{*}\mid M\text{ accepts }w\right\} $. Isn't this the general definition? How would you define $L\left(M\right)$ otherwise?

Comment: I don't think we're making any progress here. I have defined $L(M)$ repeatedly in the comments above. See my comment starting with the word "Repeating", for example.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So I don't get your definition, don't we have $L\left(M\right)\subseteq\Sigma^{*}$? If we do, is $N$ in $L(M_1)$ or in $L(M_2)$? (I think it is in neither of them, thus $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$)

Comment: No, $L(M)$ is a partial function from $\Sigma^*$ to $\Sigma^*$. Your $L(M)$ is just the support of my partial function.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus As a partial function from words that $M$ terminates on to $\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ (0 for rejects, 1 for accepts)?

Comment: Right, that makes more sense in this application. In other applications we might not allow different types of final states, but we might be interested in the output of the machine. It all depends on the exact model of Turing machine that we're using.

Answer (score 1):

Informally speaking, a property is *semantic* if it only depends on the final "outcome" of running $M$ on a given input rather than on the workings of $M$. In order to formalize this, with each Turing machine $M$, associate a partial function $\Lambda$ from inputs $\Sigma^*$ to pairs $\{0,1\} \times \Sigma^*$, where the first element denotes whether the final state accepts and rejects, and the second element denotes the output of the machine (the contents of the tape). This is a partial function, since if $M$ doesn't halt on an input $x$, then $\Lambda(x)$ is undefined.

Suppose that $P$ is a nontrivial property of partial functions $\Lambda$ of that form. Nontriviality means that there exists some Turing machine $M_+$ such that $\Lambda(M_+) \in P$, and there exists another Turing machine $M_-$ such that $\Lambda(M_-) \notin P$.

If $P$ is decidable then consider the Turing machine $Q$ which on input $x$, determines whether $\Lambda(Q) \in P$ (this self-reference can be implemented using the recursion theorem), if so runs $M_-$ on $x$, and otherwise runs $M_+$ on $x$. By construction, if $\Lambda(Q) \in P$ then $\Lambda(Q) = \Lambda(M_-) \notin P$, and if $\Lambda(Q) \notin P$ then $\Lambda(Q) = \Lambda(M_+) \in P$. In both cases we obtain a contradiction.

Crucially, the identities $\Lambda(Q) = \Lambda(M_\pm)$ implicitly rely on the fact that $\Lambda$ only captures semantic properties. The syntactic properties could well be different, since $Q$ isn't the same as $M_\pm$, it just simulates those machines.